# Remove <title> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Is there a way to remove title tag using javascript?

I tried to do this

```
var parent = document.head;
var child = document.title;
parent.removeChild(child);
```

but it failed because title tag is not a node (console said).
I need to force a Wordpress plugin to overwrite the default title tag with a custom one.

Any ideas?

Comment: This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373976/editing-the-head-section-with-javascript

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do it?

Comment: @MahbubulIslam Thanks!

Comment: @Kaiido I need to add a custom title to wordpress page through a plugin. Wordpress adds titles though the theme, I don't wanna change the theme's code because updates are gonna backtrack the process. JS wasn't a good idea finally

Comment: why don't you overwrite document.title ?

Comment: @Kaiido I guess this is what I should do. xD Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `title` property just contains a string representation of the title. It doesn't represent the element itself.

You can use any of the usual methods to get the element itself.

```
document.querySelector("title");
document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
// etc
```

Comment: Same error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: @Diprap — Works fine when I test it: http://jsbin.com/qatuqijuva/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: yes it does, but for some reason my console throws an error :O

Comment: @Diprap — Possibly you are trying to run the JS before the title element has been added to the DOM, but without an [mcve] it isn't possible to tell.

Comment: that's right, that's what I did. Thank you. My example wasn't good, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].remove()

Answer (score 0):

To set document title via JS, use:

```
document.title = "your title here"
```

Note that the title you set via JS will not be visible to Google and other search engines.

Comment: Yes, I need a seo friendly solution, this is why I need to remove the element

Comment: @Diprap — How is removing the element with client side JavaScript any friendlier to search engines than changing its value with client side JavaScript?

Comment: The script runs in a php file. The php adds a new title.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to run javascript on the php server!? how are you doing that?

Comment: @xander  <script>
var parent = document.head;
var child = document.querySelector("title");
parent.removeChild(child);
</script>

<?php other stuff here ?>

Comment: But it was a bad idea anyway

Comment: @Diprap yeah if you add a script tag like that it is only run in the client (browser) after the page is loaded. not by search engines or other web crawlers so the title may be wrong.. the question is why do you even set the title in php if you remove it later?

Comment: @xander I need to add a custom title to wordpress page through a plugin. Wordpress adds titles though the theme, I don't wanna change the theme's code because updates are gonna backtrack the process. JS wasn't a good idea finally

Answer (score 0):

You can use `your_element.removeAttribute('title');`